# How to define that how many users are login at given time in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance

if I have 1000 user which will login in 10 sec but load testing fails means 1000 users are not login in 10 sec then how we define how many numbers of user are login(count) means is there in Jmeter is any report or graph which shows the proper report like 600 users are login 400 are unable to login or anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is something you can figure out from [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report), you have `Error %` there

[image: Aggregate Report Failures]

However I would recommend increasing your load **gradually**, this way you will be able to tell for sure how many concurrent users your application can support without errors. Increase ramp-up period or use one of custom [Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) available via JMeter Plugins project.

In regards to monitoring, you can either generate an [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which provides i.e. `Active Threads Over Time` and `Response codes per second` graphs or use the JMeter Plugins equivalents:

- [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/)
- [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/)

Aforementioned (and other) plugins can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)